# Windows 10 search & apps stop working when disabling firewall

Tags: windows-10, start-menu, windows-firewall

After installing windows 10 on my new development PC, I joined my work domain (windows), disabled UAC and switched off my firewall. After that my start button had completely stopped working, no response when clicking on it, I found a solution [here](https://www.techmesto.com/fix-start-menu-broken-windows-10-technical-preview/) that enables the start button again. This worked but my search functionality is not working and store apps do not open, after clicking them, they disappear from my start menu completely.

Has anyone else experienced something similar or know of a solution?

Comment: Store apps insist on UAC

Comment: UAC is still off and apps are working, only my firewall makes a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same issue on multiple PCs. With firewall Disabled, search function is not working and sharing printers gives met the following "no endpoints available from the endpoint mapper". Re-enable the firewall service....Set it to "Automatic" startup and start the service. Then go to firewall settings, right click on "windows firewall with advanced security" and set "Firewall State" to "Off". Should fix your problem.